# WakefulBroadcastReceiver in support library vs cwac-wakeful by commonsware

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice, commonsware-cwac

I am using commonsware `WakefulIntentService` for doing wakeful work. 
Is there any advantage over using the [commonsware library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) instead of [`WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) from support library?

**This is my code using the suport library**

```
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;    

public class SimpleWakefulReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // This is the Intent to deliver to our service.
        Intent service = new Intent(context, SimpleWakefulService.class);

        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        Log.i("SimpleWakefulReceiver", "Starting service @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        startWakefulService(context, service);
    }
}

public class SimpleWakefulService extends IntentService {
    public SimpleWakefulService() {
        super("SimpleWakefulService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Log.i("SimpleWakefulReceiver", "Completed service @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        SimpleWakefulReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

[This](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) is the documentation.

1. What are the differences between them?
2. Where should i use the commonsware library instead of suport
   library?

Comment: They solve the same basic problem. `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` could, at least in theory, be used (carefully!) with a regular `Service`, and so it is more flexible. It is also part of the Android Support package, which you may already be using for other stuff, and therefore it saves you a dependency. OTOH, between April 2008 and August 2013, `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` did not exist, and so `WakefulIntentService` was the primary option.

Comment: @CommonsWare , i saw you updated the lib some months ago. At the present, does your lib is better than WakefulBroadCastReceiver ?

Comment: @CauCuKien: Rob's answer does a nice job of summarizing the differences. Beyond that, I do not know what you consider "better" to mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are almost the same.

The support library's `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` takes a partial wake lock, puts the lock ID as an extra in the `Intent` that you are supposed to give to an `IntentService` where you must call `completeWakefulIntent ()` when you're done processing. So acquiring and releasing is done in different places which is a bit of a code smell.

CommonsWare's `WakefulIntentService` does the acquiring and releasing of the partial wake lock itself.

You could use a regular `BroadcastReceiver` in combination with the `WakefulIntentService` if you agree that acquiring and releasing should be done in the same place.

If you don't mind that much and think it's more important to use a well known library so new developers (or you in a year's time) don't have to (re)learn something new then use the support library.

**update**

Also this: in the documentation for `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` it warns about the possibility of being interrupted and losing the wake lock. You would need to acquire your own wake lock in the `IntentService` to guard against that. With CommonsWare's you can just rely on it to reacquire the lock.

Comment: You mentioned about the possibility of being interrupted and losing the wake lock. But I can not find where it is on official documentation. Can you please give a link or an example to detect and acquire wake lock again?

Comment: @CauCuKien, See the developer docs for [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html). There is an example `SimpleWakefulService` class where the comments inside function `onHandleIntent(Intent intent)` warn for this possibility: "Note that when using this approach..."